# DC generator circuit

Tags: dc, generator, charging

total novice here so forgive me if I sound daft.

I’m currently building a circuit that is using a small DC motor in reverse to charge a battery. One like the Anker Powercore type. I currently have 2  capacitors in the circuit to smooth out the current but am wondering if I can use a diode to ensure that the battery doesn’t just spin the motor when not in use?

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: You might consider a bridge rectifier then whatever direction the motor spins it will produce the right polarity but, there'll be one more forward volt drop to overcome when taking energy from the generator. Charging a battery is another thing - it will probably need some electronics to do it properly and safely.

Answer (score 1):

DC Motor can generate negative voltage which destroy most of circuit especially electrolytic capacitor. So you need to rectify it using full bridge rectifier unless you can make sure that motor always turn in 1 direction you can use single diode.
anyway diode have significant power loos in low voltage application due to vorward voltage. Try to use low forward voltage diode to minimize power loss.
Or you can use mosfet as full bridge rectifier for higher efficiency.
[see this link](http://www.thetaeng.com/designIdeas/FETBridge.html)